# Control the shading of a single surface in matlab without affecting others' FaceColor

Tags: matlab, plot, surface

I've browsed through this site without finding similar questions (despite similar titles). My problem is as follows. Create a function deleteme that draws a big black patch:

```
function h = deleteme()

h = surf([0 0; 50 50], [0 50;0 50], [20 20; 20 20], 'FaceColor', [0 0 0]);

end
```

Now run a script that uses this function along with any other surface creation function.

```
close all; clear all; clc;
myfig = figure;
hold all
deleteme();
surf(peaks)
colormap(hot(128))
shading interp
hold off
```

Now the patch isn't black anymore, it's white, because shading interp affected it and assigned its color to the colormap. The problem is that i can't find a way to both interp the peaks (to make it look better) and keep the patch black except:

- Calling the black patch later after the colormap
- Playing with the colormap and the caxis etc.

My question is: can you modify the function deleteme to prevent this behavior and keep what it draws as it drew it? or can you easily modify the call to surf(peaks) to interp only peaks and not the rest? I'm looking for a solution that makes the deleteme function easy to use without relying on Matlab arcane colormap play in every plot. Of course, deleteme is only a mwe of a much bigger function...

Thanks!

Comment: I'm flabbergasted by MATLAB's images, as usual. I just always get errors "too many output elements" which seem to not make sense for me. Removed my post, If I find a way to force the shading to a single figure I'll let you know.

Comment: Yeah Matlab is a tricky gadget... thanks for the help anyway (after all, I did have to read the documentation one.more.time. :) -- as always... )

Comment: Shading is an axes property and as far as I see the problem is all your surfs are on the same axes, so when you shade it, it shades everything. I can leave the post open if you want and show the axes_handle way if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I failed at modifying the deleteme function to actually keep the pane black after a shading interp. This is really a behavior of shading -- it may be possible to limits its effects.

However I realized that 'interp' is actually one possible argument for 'FaceColor' -- I never used it as such. Thus a temporary fix (until I can really isolate the patch from the call to shading) is to set all surfaces to a manual version of shading interp like this:

```
surf(peaks, 'EdgeAlpha', 0, 'FaceColor', 'interp')
```

I'll leave the question open for a while, in case someone wants to pitch in their ideas. I'd still like to know how we can isolate a matlab object from functions like shading, alpha, etc.